# Trouble populating the listbox with Json data

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

This are my C# class from json string:

```
public class Products

        {
            public string cid { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }

        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List <Products> product  { get;set; }
            public int success { get; set; }
        }
```

C# Code:

```
void myButton_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

          WebClient wc = new WebClient();
          wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://ensignweb.com/sandbox/app/comment11.php"));
          wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

       string  MyJsonString = e.Result;
       var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(MyJsonString);



   Products products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Products>(jsonObj.ToString());
   TestList.ItemsSource = products.name;
```

}

O/p i get while debugging:

```
    string jsonObj= {
      "products": [
        {
          "cid": "1",
          "name": "bernard"
        },
        {
          "cid": "2",
          "name": "Vijay"
        },
        {
          "cid": "3",
          "name": "vikas_admin"
        },
        {
          "cid": "4",
          "name": "vikas_admin"
        },
        {
          "cid": "5",
          "name": "vikas_admin"
        },

      ],
      "success": 1
    }   

products:TestApp.TestNews.Products
```

Pls help to deserialize the above string using Json.net. Tried finding resources on the net, not useful. My Listbox is not getting populated with the source and showing as null.

Update:
the o/p i get after trying the code suggested:

```
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
TestApp.TestNews+Product
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, use this

```
[DataContract]
public class Products
{
    [DataMember (Name = "cid")]
    public string Cid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
     [DataMember(Name = "products")]
    public List<Products> ProductList { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
  private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var json = e.Result;
        var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        TestList.ItemsSource = products.ProductList; // this line was updated
    }
```

All work lgreat. Regards

Comment: I tried out your code. The ouput is got is : TestApp.TestNews.RootObject

Comment: replace this TestList.ItemsSource = products; for TestList.ItemsSource = products.ProductList; And you need to create ListBoxItemTemplate to display Items content. Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx. I also update answer

Comment: Now i got the output as TestApp.TestNews.RootObject.products

Comment: Yes, and that is - your List of products. Do you have problem with displaying listItems?

Comment: Yes... the items are not displayed..only 1 line appears. I have more than 100 items.

Comment: @Mita I answered your question "Trouble deserializing the json object in windows phone 7". Now you have list deserializing objects and you have problem with his displaying. Please, accept my answer, and start new question and here provide you code, where you set List to ListBox.

Comment: @jimpanzer.... Thanks for the advice. I have updated the question... Can you plz help me in displaying the data in the listbox